# Powerbi DAX comparing two values in the same table with the same id

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need some help with comparing two values in the same table and finally subtracting them. The data is imported from sharepoint using two different excel files both containing data from a different month.

I have created a mock table of my problem.

[image]

This is how it looks after the changes

[image]

What I need is a new measure that calculates the difference between item_new and item_old where the id is the same. I'm a beginner on dax formulas and currently don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a measure like this

```
Measure4 =
VAR _val =
    MAX ( 'Table'[value] )
VAR _id =
    MAX ( 'Table'[id] )
VAR _currentlyVisibleDate =
    MAX ( 'Table'[Date] )
VAR _immediatelyPrecedingDate =
    CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Table'[Date] ), 'Table'[Date] < _currentlyVisibleDate )
RETURN
    _val
        - CALCULATE (
            MAX ( 'Table'[value] ),
            FILTER (
                ALL ( 'Table' ),
                'Table'[Id] = _id
                    && 'Table'[Date] = _immediatelyPrecedingDate
            )
        )
```

[image: S1]

Comment: Sadly it just adds a new column measure with the same values as the ones in values

Comment: Can you please take a look?

Comment: This is my result, am I doing something wrong with the previewing?

Comment: Yes, remove `value` from the matrix. Also, don't use PowerBI's built in date hierarchy unless you ever need to. TO get rid of the hierarchy do this, Options and Settings->Options->Current File->Data Load->Time Intelligence->Untick Auto date/time

Comment: Even without the value it shows the same result.

Comment: It seems the removing of the built in date hierachy did the trick! Thanks!